# Can someone tell me how the DateTimeZone::getOffset PHP function works?

Tags: php, timezone, timezone-offset

I got this line of code:

```
echo (new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->getOffset(new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')));
```

It returns zero. But I expected it to return the difference between *UTC* and *America/New_York* time zones.

I then provided the same time zone twice:

```
echo (new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'))->getOffset(new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')));
```

I expected it to return zero because the time zones are the same. But it now returns -18000 (That's the offset between *America/New_York* and *UTC*).

In the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php) it says that getOffset() always returns the offset to GMT (=UTC). But then why is getOffset not static? And if it is always the offset relative to GMT why does the time zone in the first constructor play a role?

I know there's another *getOffset* method in the *DateTime* class which is easier to use. But i want to understand how the *getOffset* method in the *DateTimeZone* class works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The offset of a timezone is how many hours it differs from UTC. The offset of a timezone may change throughout the year depending on when [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) goes into and out of effect. So you cannot get *the offset of a timezone* just like that, since it's not a constant value. You can only interrogate a timezone what its offset from UTC is *at a given time.* That's what you pass the `DateTime` object to `getOffset` for: to ask the timezone what its offset value is for the given time. E.g.:

```
echo (new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'))->getOffset(new DateTime), PHP_EOL;
echo (new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'))->getOffset(new DateTime('+6 months'));
```

```
-18000
-14400
```

If you want to get the offset difference between two arbitrary timezones, you get their respective UTC offsets and subtract them.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for a way to get the offset between PHP's current default timezone and UTC. I went down the rabbit hole with `DateTimeZone::getOffset`, but it turns out there's a much easier way:

```php
$offset = date('O');
// Returns a string like '-0400' 

$offset = date('P');
// Returns a string like '-04:00' 

$offset = date('Z');
// Returns the offset in seconds, e.g. '-14400'
```

To be clear, this gets whatever the timezone offset is *right now*, but I imagine that's what is wanted most of the time.

You can switch PHP's current timezone with `date_default_timezone_set()`.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php